# search and replace \n or \t with and empty space

Tags: regex, search, replace, gedit

Can anyone teach me how to search and replace \n or \t and replace it with an "empty" space? I tried using the search and replace in GEDIT, but it just doesn't change. I'm using GEDIT by the way.

sample:

Hi I am `\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\` John Doe`n\t\t\t\t\t` I live in BLAH BLAH.

Output:

Hi I am John Doe I live in BLAH BLAH. 
How to do this?

Comment: you want to know how your editor works ? or do you use any kind of language like php or javascript ?

Comment: Specify the language or application (if applicable) you are using.

Comment: Here's the scenario. I used print($statement) in my javascript and copied it into my gedit. Now, it has lots of \n and \t in it. I want to get rid of it. what to do? thanks

Comment: Be clear in your question.  It's not even clear whether those are _actual_ newlines/tabs or `\n`/`\t`.

Comment: The string I copied is generated using "print" in the ajax/js

Answer (score 3):

Although this thread is now 5 years old the answers do not really suffice so here is a working answer;

The most simple way to replace newline and tab characters (\n & \t) use the backslash to tell gEdit search you don't want to search for an actual newline but for the chars that represent a new line;

`\\n` or `\\t`

Answer (score 2):

Replace `\s+` with a single space.

`\s` means 'any white space character'
`+` means 'one or more'

So `\s+` means 'one or more white space characters'. You'd want to replace those with a singe space.

Answer (score -2):

Replace text in gedit

- Open the Replace tool by clicking Search ▸ Replace or press Ctrl+H.
- Enter the text that you wish to replace into the 'Search for:' field.
- Enter the new, replacement text into the 'Replace with:' field.
- Once you have entered the original and replacement text, select your
  desired replacement options:
- To replace only the next matching portion of text, click Replace.
- To replace all occurrences of the searched-for text, click Replace
  All.

[Source](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-replace.html.en)

Comment: I have done this. It just cannot find "\n" or "\t" since it is a newspace or tab